# Adding a classpath to my jar through Manifest file

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest

I built a jar file and I need to get access to a folder that's outside of it.

In my jar I have a `MANIFEST.MF` file. If i add the folder to it will I be able to use it?

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.petapilot.migrations.MigrationsApplication
```

Or is is it a better opinion to set it using the flag `classpath`when I run my jar through the command line?